# touch: cannot touch '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new': No such file or directory

Tags: apt, dpkg, sudo

When I try to run `sudo dpkg --configure --pending` I am getting error

```
dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new': No such file or directory
```

Then I try these commands

```
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade
```

But after the 1st command I am getting an error

```
touch: cannot touch '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new': No such file or directory
```

Comment: have you tried navigating to the directory first before issuing the commands in terminal?

Comment: @24601 yes, I did but got the same error

Comment: sounds like you are missing `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` altogether.